# Ping, обработать процент потерянных пакетов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Привет всем… Написал программу, который делает мониторинг сети, если нет соединение, запускает другой скрипт для рестарта модема. Сам код

```py
import os
import schedule
import time
import pyautogui

def host():
    hostname = "10.0.0.21"
    response = os.system("ping "+hostname+" -n 1 ")
    if response == 0:
        return (host)
    else:
        os.system(r'c:/watchdog/k.bat'), pyautogui.press('F10')
host()
schedule.every(2).minutes.do(host)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Но есть одна проблема: если из 20 покетов хоть один раз пингуется, оператор else не работает. Хочу добавить условие, если потерия (LOST) состовляет 60% и больше, сработал else. Как реализовать это?

Comment: что означает "не работает"? Оператор работает 100%. Если вам кажется, что не работает, значит, у вас неправильное понимание того, что происходит во время выполнения кода.

Comment: повторите `os.system("ping "+hostname+" -n 1 ")` в цикле 20 раз и посчитайте число провалов ...

Comment: Если я правильно тебя понял, тебе нужен оператор 'elif' для отслеживания пинга и соответственного реагирования на это. Т.е. тебе надо в функцию добавить блок 'elif' с проверкой пинга. За сетевые функции не особо шарю, но если надо могу поискать функции которые тебе помогут.

Comment: else  работает если  100% нет сети. Однако, если  хоть один раз пингуется, else не работает

Comment: повторю вопрос - что означает фраза "else не работает"?

Comment: Else работает, если сеть отсуствует и lost = 100%.  Условно пакет пингов 20. Если из 19 пингов будет полажителный только 1, оператор else не работает, работает return (host). то есть в место того, что бы сделать перезагрузку модема, работает таймер для долнейшой проверки пинг

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодарю всем, кто помог... рабочий код выглядет так

```
import subprocess
import re
import pyautogui
import os
import schedule
import time

def host(hostname="192.168.1.1"):
    try:
        response = subprocess.check_output(
                ['ping', '-n', '5', hostname],
                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                universal_newlines=True
            )
        print(response)
        pattern = r"\d{0,}\%"
        lost = int(re.findall(pattern, response)[0].replace("%",''))
        print(f"Lost {lost}%")
        if lost < 60:
            return (host)
        else:
            os.system(r'C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/a.bat'), pyautogui.press('F10')
    except Exception as err:
        os.system(r'C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/a.bat'), pyautogui.press('F10')
        # для теста
        # print(f"Something went wrong. Error is {err}")
host(hostname="192.168.1.1")
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(host)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: После того как наберете чуть опыта, вернитесь к данному коду и уберите так называемый `хардкодинг`.

Comment: я инженер микроэлектроники. придумать, ремонтировать электрические схемы и платы мое основное дело сегодня. Паралельно учу питон. Хотя в дипломе написанно, что я программист, я не любил программирование,  особенно C, C++ который мы учили. Если тогда  учили бы питон, то я наверника стал бы программистом!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```py
import os
import schedule
import time
import pyautogui

results = []

def host():
    global results
    hostname = "10.0.0.21"

    results = [os.system("ping "+hostname+" -n 1 ")] + results[:19]

    if sum(results) < 20 * 0.6:
        return (host)
    else:
        results = []
        os.system(r'c:/watchdog/k.bat'), pyautogui.press('F10')
    # else:
    #     os.system(r'c:/watchdog/k.bat'), pyautogui.press('F10')
host()
schedule.every(2).minutes.do(host)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Перенаправьте свой вывод в переменную, используя `subprocess`

```py
import subprocess
host = "10.0.0.21"
response = subprocess.check_output(
        ['ping', '-n', '1', host],
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, 
        universal_newlines=True 
    )
```

`response` будет содержать строку с выводом. И воспользуйтесь например регулярным выражением, чтобы достать процент потеряных пакетов

```py
import re
pattern = r"\d{0,}\%" 
lost = re.findall(pattern, response) 
print(lost)

# OUT
# ['0%']
```

Эту строку думаю не будет сложности обработать, чтобы достать значение.

Как нибудь так:

```py
import subprocess
import os
import re
import pyautogui

def host(hostname="192.168.1.1"):
    try:
        response = subprocess.check_output(
                ['ping', '-n', '5', hostname],
                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,  
                universal_newlines=True 
            )
        print(response)
        pattern = r"\d{0,}\%" 
        lost = int(re.findall(pattern, response)[0].replace("%",''))
        print(f"Lost {lost}%")
        if lost < 60:
            return (host)
        else:
            os.system(r'c:/watchdog/k.bat'), pyautogui.press('F10')
    except Exception as err:
        # раскомментить 
        # os.system(r'c:/watchdog/k.bat'), pyautogui.press('F10')
        # это для теста
        print(f"Something went wrong. Error is {err}")
```

Здесь добавлю тест с пингом на `google.com`. Также изменил количество пингов с 1 на 5 и вывел ответ выполнения.

```py
host("google.com")
```

Вывод

```py
Pinging google.com [142.250.74.142] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 142.250.74.142: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=51
Reply from 142.250.74.142: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=51
Reply from 142.250.74.142: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=51
Reply from 142.250.74.142: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=51
Reply from 142.250.74.142: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=51

Ping statistics for 142.250.74.142:
    Packets: Sent = 5, Received = 5, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 21ms, Maximum = 30ms, Average = 23ms

Lost 0%
<function host at 0x00000142D9D054C0>
```

Тест на исключение:

```py
host("h") 

# OUT
# Something went wrong. Error is Command '['ping', '-n', '5', 'hostname']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

У вас вместо вывода строки с ошибкой, оставьте директиву вызова перегрузки оборудования.

Comment: интерестный код, однако не работает. взать хотя бы

response = subprocess.check_output(
            ['ping', '-n', '1', hostname],
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,  
            universal_newlines=True 

даже не пингуется. я пробовал через subprocess.Popen, или subprocess.run. Однако взать Lost не получается

Comment: скопировал код, который вы прислали, запускаю, резлультат "Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: У меня с конструкции "try-except" код вообще не работает

Comment: C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\EasyPay\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/EasyPay/rrr.py
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/EasyPay/rrr.py", line 5
    def host("192.168.1.1"):
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: поправил hostname. и все же программа не  работает при отсутвии сети, Условие Else не работает(((   Something went wrong. Error is Command '['ping', '-n', '5', '192.168.1.1']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: УРАА! заработааала пограмма....Спасибо вам ОГРОМНОЕ!!! я новичок в сфере прогаммирования. алгоритны придумать получается легко, а вот написать в языке программирования дается не легко.

Comment: @gevorg-x На здоровье, разбирайтесь и не бросайте. Ответ можете отметить как принятый и я удалю все свои комментарии, дабы не засорять лишним здесь

Comment: Спасибо Вам еще раз... через 4 часа смогу отметить как  принятый!

Comment: @gevorg-x мой может сразц